# VGA passthrough using virt-manager

Tags: linux, graphics-card, virtual-machine, virtualization, pci-express

I'm following [this tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/VGAPassthrough)

See what I've done:

```
lz@blade:~$ egrep -q '^flags.*(svm|vmx)' /proc/cpuinfo && echo virtualization extensions available
virtualization extensions available
lz@blade:~$ lspci -vnn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:5904] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Razer USA Ltd. Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [1a58:6752]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 [8086:5916] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Razer USA Ltd. HD Graphics 620 [1a58:6752]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at db000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
...
```

There's no other thing on `00:02.x`, so the soundcard is not shared by this GPU. Note that the manufacter/model is `8086 5916`

Then I did:

```
lz@blade:~$ sudo modprobe vfio
[sudo] password for lz: 
lz@blade:~$ sudo modprobe vfio_pci
```

And finally:

```
echo 8086 5916 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id
```

According to what I understood, I should now see VFIO in the output of lscpi, right?

I don't want to start QEMU manually because I use a lot of virtual machines with lots of different configurations. Would be easier to just go on virt-manager and add the vfio PCI device using the GUI. But first it must appear in the list. What am I doing wrong?

PS: adding the GPU itself as a PCI device in the virt-manager GUI didn't work for me, it says something about host PCI devices being not possible to add, but anyway

**UPDATE:**
[image]

Here's what happend if I try to add the VGA pci itself

Comment: @dsstorefile it's the same. I just selected PIC device 02:00 on virt-manager